# iOS 11 Files app - Google Drive Large Files import issue

Tags: google-drive-api, ios11, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I'am using Files app in iOS 11.
The Files app is configured for iCloud, Google Drive and DropBox

Am able to open text or CSV files with size > 200 MB on iCloud and DropBox.
But when i open a text or CSV files with size > 200 MB on Google Drive, i dont see the file contents.  Small text files are not an issue with Google Drive.

The issue is also apparent when we use the UI Kit API - UIDocumentPickerViewController
As the UIDocumentPicker Apple UIKit API uses the same Files App interface and exhibits the same behaviour, we see the same error thrown by the API.

As soon as i select a text or json or xml file > 200 MB, i see these log entries and the 'documentPickerWasCancelled' event is invoked.

> 2017-12-22 16:19:30.233311+0530 DocumentPickerTestingGrounds[3036:431736] [DocumentManager] Failed to copy the imported file into the local container (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection from pid 2943" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection from pid 2943})
>   2017-12-22 16:19:30.264298+0530 DocumentPickerTestingGrounds[3036:431689] [UIDocumentLog] UIDocumentPickerViewController : didPickDocumentURLs called with nil or 0 URLS

Now i feel its a bug with Google Drive or Files app implementation for G Drive.

Am unable to find any such reference material or bug note on this issue online.
I tried deleting and re-installing Google Drive app.  Its still same behaviour.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i had to use Google Drive API and then i could download files > 200MB size.

So there is an issue with Files app in iOS 11 and GoogleDrive.